# How to match a string against a list of regex expression

Tags: regex, list, scala

List3 contains the list of element that are regular expression pattern fetched from DB.  I want to print `Success` if any of the regex matches else `Failure`

```
val list3 = List(Test("A..C.."), Test("DF...."))
val testExpr ="DF1C13"
val s3 = list3
    .filter(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)
    .map(_ => "Success")
```

Actual Output

```
 List(Success)
```

**Expected** 
Simple String

```
"Success" //Successful match
"Failure" //If match fails
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez this will return a list which I do not want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you only need to know if it satifies one of the regex, you can go for `exists`, instead of `filter` and `map`, it will return a `true` if any of the regex is `true`, and `false` if none of them are `true`:

```
val resulBool: Boolean = list3
    .exists(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)
val s3 = if (resulBool) "Success" else "Failure"
```

But if you want that the expression satisfies all the regex, you can go for `forAll`, that will only return `true` if all the regex are `true`

```
val resulBool: Boolean = list3
    .forall(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)
val s3 = if (resulBool) "Success" else "Failure"
```

An example of exists and forall [here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/K4V9Frg/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.forall` to run predicate against all values of a collection

```
if (list3.forall(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)) "Success" else "Failure"
// "Failure"
```

or if inside a `.map` if you want to have a result of every match as suggested by @The fourth bird:

```
list3.map(x => if (x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches) "Success" else "Failure")
// List("Failure", "Success")
```

or `.exists` if you want to check if at least one matcher works as suggested by @Alfilercio

```
if (list3.exists(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)) "Success" else "Failure"
// "Success"
```

BTW, if you plan to reuse these regexp after fetching them from DB, I would suggest to not recompute them every time as this is expensive.

```
val patterns = list3.map(x => x.s.r.pattern)

if (patterns.forall(x => x.matcher(testExpr).matches)) "Success" else "Failure"
```

Comment: edited question with ``testExpr`` instead of ``"testExpr"``.Can you please update the answer

Comment: I get failure for my pattern , it should success for ``val testExpr ="DF1C13"``

Comment: the output is not correct , I need success and I get failure

Comment: Then you have wrong pattern - `"A..C.."` does NOT match against `"DF1C13"`

Comment: but DF.... is right match , I want once the match is found it should return Success else Fialure

Comment: Then you should clarify in your question what do you mean by "result of all matches": are all patterns matched or is any pattern matched. `.forall` will check if ALL are matched, `.exists` if ANY is matched and `.map` will give you list of results of each match.

Comment: I expect the answer shared by Alfilercio. Updated the question

Comment: Then update your question as well. Nobody can tell what you actually want unless they read all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could map and test the outcome of the expression and omit the filter part, or else you will remove them from the collection.

```
val list3 = List(Test("A..C.."), Test("DF...."))
val testExpr ="DF1C13"
val s3 = list3
    .map(x => if(x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches) "Success" else  "Failure")
```

Output

```
s3: List[String] = List(Failure, Success)
```

---

You could also keep the filter as `matches` returns a boolean, and omit the map. Then check if the s3 collection is not empty and return either Success or Failure as a string.

```
val list3 = List(Test("A..C.."), Test("DF...."))
val testExpr ="DF1C13"
val s3 = list3
.filter(x => x.s.r.pattern.matcher(testExpr).matches)

if (s3.nonEmpty) "Success" else "Failure"
```

Output

```
res0: String = Success
```

Comment: I need String not list of string

Comment: But if you only want a string, how do you know which one has succeeded or failed?

Comment: Once the match is found in the given list , I should print Success else Failure

Comment: @coder25 Then you can check if the s3 collection is not empty.